# Oracle Materialized View fails ORA-12840 and ORA-06512:

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle12c

I've recently move from Oracle 10g to Oracle 12c and when I try to create a Materialized View I'm getting this error

```
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-12840: cannot access a remote table after parallel/insert direct load txn
ORA-06512: at "Internal_function", line 11
12840. 00000 -  "cannot access a remote table after parallel/insert direct load txn"
*Cause:    Within a transaction, an attempt was made to perform distributed
           access after a PDML or insert direct  statement had been issued.
*Action:   Commit/rollback the PDML transaction first, and then perform
           the distributed access, or perform the distributed access before the
           first PDML statement in the transaction.
```

I'm confused because on Oracle 10g the Materialized view works fine but if I execute the same SQL instruction On Oracle 12c I get the error.

This is the SQL instructions that I used to create the materialized view

```
create materialized view vm_xxx as 
SELECT 
      id,      
      Internal_function(id) Internal_value
 FROM tableA
```

And this is the code of Internal_function function

```
 create or replace FUNCTION        "Internal_function"
(
  v_id in varchar2
) RETURN VARCHAR2   AS


total_count  number;
RETURN_VALUE varchar2(1):='N';
BEGIN

    SELECT  count(*)
    INTO total_count
    FROM
    tableA e,
    tableB t
    WHERE
    E.id =T.id(+)
    AND
    (
    e.v_id1 = v_id
    OR
    e.v_id2= v_id
    OR
    T.v_id3= v_id);   

    if total_count > 0 then
      RETURN_VALUE:='Y';
    end if;

  return RETURN_VALUE;
END Internal_function;
```

How can tell me what could i do to solve this issue? o suggest me alternatives to create this materialized view

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
create materialized view test_mw as 
SELECT e.id,
       case
         when count(*) > 0 then
          'Y'
         else
          'N'
       end as internal_value
FROM   tableA e,
       tableB t
WHERE  E.id = T.id(+)
AND    (e.v_id1 = v_id OR e.v_id2 = v_id OR T.v_id3 = v_id)
group  by e.id;
```